# How to recode factor based on condition in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to recode a factor based on a condition, however, I am not being able to.
Could you please help me?

Here is my code

```
if(df$ID = "x"){
df$ID <- recode_factor(df$ID, x == "Stack")
  
}else if (df$ID = "y"){
df$ID <- recode_factor(df$ID, y=="Stack")
  
} else {
df$ID <- recode_factor(df$ID, "Other")
}
```

I want to do the following: 
 if the column ID has a value x or y, it shall be renamed Stack. If it has any other value, it shall be renamed Other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the vectorized `ifelse` rather than `if`, which only checks a single value.

Suppose your data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = factor(c("y", "x", "a", "x", "x", "b", "y")))

df
#>   ID
#> 1  y
#> 2  x
#> 3  a
#> 4  x
#> 5  x
#> 6  b
#> 7  y
```

Then you can refactor with the single line:

```
df$ID <- factor(ifelse(df$ID == "x" | df$ID == "y", "Stack", "Other"))
```

or, equivalently:

```r
df$ID <- factor(ifelse(df$ID %in% c("x", "y"), "Stack", "Other"))
```

Either of which result in:

```
df
#>      ID
#> 1 Stack
#> 2 Stack
#> 3 Other
#> 4 Stack
#> 5 Stack
#> 6 Other
#> 7 Stack
```

You can also use the following version, which doesn't require `ifelse` at all

```r
df$ID <- factor(c("Other", "Stack")[df$ID %in% c("x", "y") + 1])
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks - I have added in a couple of extra options using `%in%`